# entity_load() not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is their anything wrong with the following? The $entity variable is not returning anything.

I am trying to get an entity object using `entity_load()` as follows:

```
$entity = entity_load('ENTITY_NAME', IDS, $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE);
```

*ENTITY_NAME and IDS are obviously not the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is IDS an array of valid IDs for your ENTITY_NAME?

Can you run and see if this works:

```
$entity = entity_load('ENTITY_NAME', IDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'IDS' had span tags on them generated by views and obviously didn't parse them as integers.